# Not receiving some emails after domain transfer

Tags: web-hosting, dns, email, dns-servers, domain-transfer

I transferred my wife's web hosting, domain & email from One.com over to Fasthosts.
I'd used fasthosts for 2 other email only hosting accounts with no problem at all.

When it transferred it seemed OK until my wife said she wasn't getting all emails.
So i did a test from various different email accounts and noticed some came through OK whereas others different.

Emails from gmail and yahoo worked ok. Those from outlook and my work's domain didn't.
I whitelisted/trusted various TLD's such as *@.co.uk / *@.com etc
After I did this the ones from outlook came through OK. Odd as all this setting should have done was stopped the emails going into junk (there is nothing in the junk folder).

However this didn't solve the issue as both my work's domain and email from some of her customers were still not coming through. I've since had over a week of messages and calls to Fasthosts where they insist it is the DNS propogation that is the issue. However we've had multiple resets and waiting 48 hours to no avail. I've done this with various sites 10's of times but never had this issue.

The domain is friendlygardener.co.uk

I'm ready to tear my hair out, cut my losses and move provider at this point. Just wanted to put the question out to see if there are any experts here with any suggestions to try.
OR recommendations for a good (not too expensive) UK web host to transfer to.

Comment: I would also close this as being specific to a single website.  Questions here must be more than just "what is wrong with my site" so that they will be useful when others search for similar problems.

Comment: If the below answered your question you should accept it as your answer.

Answer (score 2):

DNS propagation doesn't exist, this is a myth. If you look at authoritative nameservers you see changes **immediately**.

And you should indeed look at that, or just use DNSViz, a good online troubleshooting tool explaining you immediately the problem:
https://dnsviz.net/d/friendlygardener.co.uk/Yngmkw/dnssec/

[image: DNSViz output]

You have a DNSSEC misconfiguration, breaking all DNS resolutions on your domain, for some people, those using a recursive validating nameserver.

The registry publishes `DS` record for your domain, that does not match any `DNSKEY` record in your zone. This is akin to a lame delegation but since this is on the secure path, the chain of validation is broken hence your domain will appear as not existing at all for anyone checking DNSSEC data (and both CloudFlare and Google public recursive services do validate DNSSEC).

This is what you need to address. Your domain was probably DNSSEC enabled at old provider and you didn't look at that when transferring it and your new provider doesn't handle DNSSEC or you didn't enable it, so now it is broken.
(FWIW, transferring DNSSEC enabled domains is currently still a can of worms and has to be handled with a lot of caution; the new DNS provider/registrar should help on that and advise in advance of the proper steps to follow to avoid problems).

The shortest (but not best) path now is to go at your registrar (which is also FastHosts according to whois; do remember though that domain name registrar and DNS provider are two separate jobs, they can be done by the same company but this is not mandatory and has both benefits and drawbacks), and remove any DNSSEC information, aka DS data.

The current TTL on the `DS` record at registry is 1 hour so normally after this delay, everything should be back to normal.

The best/proper path would be to fix DNSSEC at your domain, which means going to your DNS provider AND registrar (which are the same company), so that you get the proper `DS` data to input to the registry.

Comment: Upvote for https://dnsviz.net

Comment: "DNS propagation doesn't exist, this is a myth ... the current TTL on the DS record at registry is 1 hour so normally after this delay" -- That is exactly what DNS propagation is. I agree that changes at the authoritative name servers happen immediately, but not everybody sees that until the TTL expires.  I wouldn't describe propagation as a myth, I'd say that there are typically ways to test things even before all TTLs may have expired.

Comment: "That is exactly what DNS propagation is. ". No it is not. "propagation" implies that changes go from top to bottom, and they do not, and people using "propagation" often attach to it some hardcoded delay like 24h or 48hours typically as a "magical" value somehow coming from nowhere, where there are only TTLs, and of varying values. And that nothing happens before, which is false, because it depends of each cache current content, and bottom up requests. So I stand by the fact that there is no propagation in the DNS and using that term is wrong and misleading. And I will always say so.